# not saving when using setDidReceiveDataSelector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, save, asihttprequest

i want to download a file and show the progress bar
i was able to do this.
now , i want to show the progress value in a label and use this code to progress init and update label :

```
[queue setDelegate:self];
[queue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(updateLabel)];
[queue setDownloadProgressDelegate:progress];
[queue setShowAccurateProgress:YES];

ASIHTTPRequest *request;
request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];

[request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:[filePath stringByAppendingString:@".download"]];
[request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];

[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(updateLabel)];
[request setDidReceiveDataSelector:@selector(updateLabel)];

[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
[request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO]; 
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:filePath]; 
[queue addOperation:request];
[queue go];
```

but not save in the destination path !

and when i clear this code :

```
[request setDidReceiveDataSelector:@selector(updateLabel)];
```

saving done !

what is problem ?

i want to update label text when progress value changed

Comment: Hope this will help you out http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#tracking_download_progress_for_a_set_of_requests

Comment: This is orthogonal to your question - but we see questions about `ASIHTTPRequest` frequently - often new apps in development.  You should note that [`ASHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D) is no longer under development and the developer is recommending other networking libraries instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is what something you need to do with the Main Thread. Updating the UI of the application is performed by the main thread rather than any of the background thread.

Or

alternatively you can use the below code snippet which works for me :

```
- (void)fetchThisURLFiveTimes:(NSURL *)url
{
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request addOperation:request];
   [request cancelAllOperations];
   [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:myProgressIndicator];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueComplete:)];

   [request go];
}

- (void)queueComplete:(ASINetworkQueue *)queue
{
   NSLog(@"Value: %f", [myProgressIndicator progress]);
   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateLabel) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; 
}
```